# How to read and assign variables from an API return that's formatted as Dictionary-List-Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary

So I'm trying to learn Python here, and would appreciate any help you guys could give me.  I've written a bit of code that asks one of my favorite websites for some information, and the api call returns an answer in a dictionary.  In this dictionary is a list.  In that list is a dictionary.  This seems crazy to me, but hell, I'm a newbie.

I'm trying to assign the answers to variables, but always get various error messages depending on how I write my {},[], or ().  Regardless, I can't get it to work.  How do I read this return?  Thanks in advance.

```
{

            "answer":
                [{"widgets":16,
                  "widgets_available":16,
                  "widgets_missing":7,
                  "widget_flatprice":"156",
                  "widget_averages":15,
                  "widget_cost":125,
                  "widget_profit":"31",
                  "widget":"90.59"}],
            "result":true

}
```

Edited because I put in the wrong sample code.

Comment: You'll need to show an actual example of your code.  The code you pasted is not valid Python; it seems to be missing a closing brace somewhere.  Also, there are no lists in the data structure you showed.

Comment: Yeah, I got a little trigger happy on my cut and paste.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: What error messages do you get? I assume the API is returning JSON, not a Python dictionary - correct?

Comment: I think so... although I'm not super familiar with JSON.  But the above code is literally the text that is returned.  The error message depends on what I've done to try to pick apart the code- which is a lot of different things.  For instance errors on converting string to integers, unreadable strings, a bunch of others.  Sorry to be vague.

Comment: It's probably JSON and you are getting error messages because you are treating it like a Python dict. Please share your error message(s).

Comment: You need to show *your actual code*: that is, not just the data, but the code you are trying to use to read this data, along with the error(s) you're getting.

Comment: I haven't copied my error messages, but you're putting me on the right track already :)

Comment: @Danimal - one of the very first things that you should provide when asking for help with an error - is the error message itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your code, but the de-facto way of doing this is by using the `requests` module, like this:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.example.com/api/v1/something'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json() # converts the returned json into a Python dictionary

for item in data['answer']:
    print(item['widgets'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not using the `requests` library (see Burhan's answer), you would use the `json` module like so:

```
data = '{"answer":
           [{"widgets":16,
             "widgets_available":16,
             "widgets_missing":7,
             "widget_flatprice":"156",
             "widget_averages":15,
             "widget_cost":125,
             "widget_profit":"31",
             "widget":"90.59"}],
         "result":true}'

import json

data = json.loads(data)

# Now you can use it as you wish
data['answer'] # and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

First I will mention that to access a dictionary value you need to use ["key"] and not {}. see here an [Python dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) syntax.

Here is a step by step walkthrough on how to build and access a similar data structure:

First create the main dictionary:

```
t1 = {"a":0, "b":1}
```

you can access each element by:

```
t1["a"]  # it'll return a 0
```

Now lets add the internal list:

```
t1["a"] = ["x",7,3.14]
```

and access it using:

```
t1["a"][2]  # it'll return 3.14
```

Now creating the internal dictionary:

```
t1["a"][2] = {'w1':7,'w2':8,'w3':9}
```

And access:

```
t1["a"][2]['w3']  # it'll return 9
```

Hope it helped you.